# how to add calender view according to plan visit list in xamarin.form

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

[image: Example of Calendar Events]

How to add events in a calendar?

Comment: It depends on the calendar plugin you are using.
This looks like Telerik Calendar, right?

Comment: i am not using telerik  calender . i just show image for example for understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Adding Events or appointments depends on what type of calendar plugin you will be using.

I recommend checking out Syncfusion SFCalendar which is free for community and you can use all features if the conditions apply to you.

Check out the appointments section and you can also download the demos from the App Store or google play.

I don't work for Syncfusion but I tested and loved their products.

[Syncfusion SFCalendar Overview](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/sfcalendar/overview)

Comment: i have read in xamarin calendar demo, but i don't understand how to implement it in my code
i want to have calendar on the top, listview in the bottom of calendar and when i clicked one of day in calendar, there is a list of events in that day..

Comment: @brijeshkumaryadav it's very simple actually. But I can't just spoon-feed you the code. You need to try to implement it yourself and when you get really stuck with something we will help you. This is the right way to learn.

Comment: As hints, you need create a model for the event which will contain the variables such as time, place, and any data you want to show. After that create a list of that type and bind it in the Xaml. And finally, on date clicked event, load the list with the new values according to the clicked date.

Comment: On GitHub there are some plugin

XamForms.Controls.Calendar how to be implemented??

Comment: check out my answer there and also it includes the answer of the developer. 

Please research a little bit more before asking